# Get images from the array and embed them in the email body

Tags: arrays, email, phpmailer

I am using wordpress cms and PHPMailer. In my form-processor I have this simple loop which generates an array of selected images. Please check the relevant block of code below. It basically produces an array of images according to the post ids provided via a form. I need to pull all these images and embed them **in the body of the email**. Please note that I do not intend to send these images as attachments. Here is a stripped code version.

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'John@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'John Doe';
$email->Subject   = 'This is the subject of the message';                        
$body = '<table><tr><td>';

$body .=  
    $args = array('post__in' => $short_ids, 'post_type' => 'post');
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>
    <?php $images = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'cover' );

    $img_url = $images[0];
    $email->AddEmbeddedImage($img_url, '1243');?>
    <img src="cid:1243"/>               
    <?php endforeach;?>

$body = '</td></tr></table><tr>';
$email->MsgHTML($body);
$email->IsHTML(true); 
$email->AddAddress( 'email@gmail.com' );
$email->Send();
```

> I just get the word **`Array`** in the body of the email. How do I convert this array >into images to be embed into the email body ? So I think I basically need help with array manipulation.

---

**UPDATE** : Here is an alternate code I came up with that successfully fetches the images from the array and actually echoes out onto the page but **does not embed** the images in the email body.

```
foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>
  <?php $images = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'cover' );
  $img_urls = $images[0]; ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $img_urls;?>">
<?php endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you do not necessarily need AddEmbeddedImage for embedding images in the body with PHPMailer. You can do it in the native php way by appending the results of the code to the $body variable, which then uses PHPMailer's `$email->MsgHTML($body)` to get the output. Here is the relevant code that pulls several post-thumbnails according to post-ids stored in `$select_ids` and appends the result to `$body` variable.

```
$args = array('post__in' => $select_ids, 'post_type' => 'post');

$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($posts as $post) {
$images = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'cover');
$body .=    '<a href="'.get_permalink().'"><img src="'.$images[0].'"></a>';             
}
```

If you are relatively new, I would like to point out a silly mistake I made in the script. If you are setting an array like in first and second line make sure not to put `$body` or `$body. =` variable in front of it or else your code will output an unwanted word `Array` in your html output and that again was the reason I was getting the word `Array` in my html output.